# Export/Import file issues in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to write code for a password manager that can export or import a list of passwords in .txt or .rtf file format.

I have this code:

```
import json
import ssl
import random
import string
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Disable SSL certificate verification temporarily
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


class PasswordManager:
    def __init__(self):
        # Master password used to access the password manager
        self.master_password = "keem"

        # Generate a random key for encryption and decryption
        self.key = Fernet.generate_key()

        # Dictionary to store the site names and encrypted passwords
        self.passwords = {}

        # Initialize the main Tkinter window
        self.root = Tk()

        # Title for our window
        self.root.title("Password Manager")

        # Creating the master password entry box
        self.master_password_label = Label(self.root, text="Master Password:")
        self.master_password_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.master_password_entry = Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.master_password_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Creating the site name entry box
        self.site_label = Label(self.root, text="Site Name:")
        self.site_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.site_entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.site_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Displaying the password requirements
        self.requirements = Label(self.root, text="Password Requirements: At least 8 characters, contains letters and numbers.")
        self.requirements.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # Creating the password entry box
        self.password_label = Label(self.root, text="Password:")
        self.password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.password_entry = Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

        # Creating the buttons
        self.store_button = Button(self.root, text="Store Password", command=self.store_password)
        self.store_button.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.generate_button = Button(self.root, text="Generate Password", command=self.generate_password)
        self.generate_button.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.view_button = Button(self.root, text="View Passwords", command=self.view_passwords)
        self.view_button.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.export_button = Button(self.root, text="Export Passwords", command=self.export_passwords)
        self.export_button.grid(row=7, column=1)

        self.import_button = Button(self.root, text="Import Passwords", command=self.import_passwords)
        self.import_button.grid(row=8, column=1)

        # Running the Tkinter event loop
        self.root.mainloop()

    def encrypt_password(self, password):
        f = Fernet(self.key)
        encrypted_password = f.encrypt(password.encode())
        return encrypted_password

    def decrypt_password(self, encrypted_password):
        f = Fernet(self.key)
        decrypted_password = f.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode()
        return decrypted_password

    @staticmethod
    def check_password_strength(password):
        has_number = any(char.isdigit() for char in password)
        has_letter = any(char.isalpha() for char in password)

        if len(password) < 8 or not has_number or not has_letter:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def store_password(self):
        master = self.master_password_entry.get()
        site = self.site_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        if master != self.master_password:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid master password!")
            return

        if not self.check_password_strength(password):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password does not meet requirements.")
            return

        encrypted_password = self.encrypt_password(password)

        self.passwords[site] = encrypted_password

        self.update_password_list()
        self.master_password_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.site_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.password_entry.delete(0, 'end')

        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Password stored successfully!")

    def generate_password(self):
        while True:
            letters = string.ascii_letters
            digits = string.digits
            password = ''.join(random.choice(letters + digits) for i in range(12))

            if self.check_password_strength(password):
                break

        self.password_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.password_entry.insert(0, password)

    def view_passwords(self):
        password_list = ""
        for site, encrypted_password in self.passwords.items():
            decrypted_password = self.decrypt_password(encrypted_password)
            password_list += f"Site: {site}\nPassword: {decrypted_password}\n\n"

        if password_list:
            messagebox.showinfo("Stored Passwords", password_list)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Stored Passwords", "No passwords stored.")

    def import_passwords(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Rich Text Files", "*.rtf")))
        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, "r") as file:
                    self.passwords = json.load(file)
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Passwords imported successfully!")
                    self.update_password_list()
            except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError):
                self.passwords = {}
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Failed to import passwords!")

    def export_passwords(self):
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Rich Text Files", "*.rtf")))
        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, "w") as file:
                    json.dump(self.passwords, file)
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Passwords exported successfully!")
            except Exception:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Failed to export passwords!")

    def update_password_list(self):
        self.password_listbox.delete(0, END)
        for site in self.passwords:
            self.password_listbox.insert(END, site)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    password_manager = PasswordManager()
    password_manager.run()
```

But it shows a message that says "Error Failed to export passwords!", indicating that an exception was caught. The export also doesn't export in the correct format. The import function is not much more helpful here.

I tried modifying the `import_passwords()` method to handle importing passwords from both .txt and .rtf files, using `filedialog.askopenfilename` to let the user select the file to import.

I tried modifying the `export_passwords()` method to handle exporting passwords to both .txt and .rtf files, using `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` to let the user choose the filename and location for export.

I tried updating the import and export filetypes in the `filedialog.askopenfilename` and `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` functions to include both .txt and .rtf file formats.

I tried removing the unnecessary `defaultextension=".txt"` argument in the `asksaveasfilename` function since the user can choose either .txt or .rtf format.

I tried removing the `load_passwords()` method as I am no longer using the `passwords.json` file for storage.

I tried using appropriate exception handling for import and export operations, catching `FileNotFoundError` and `json.JSONDecodeError` exceptions to display relevant error messages.

None of these have fixed the problem. What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should print the actual exception instead of a generic message, so you'll know why it failed.

Comment: `messagebox.showerror("Error", "Failed to export passwords!")` That is a **terrible** way to handle the exception, because it **deliberately** hides the information about what actually went wrong.  It would be **much** better if you took out the try/except wrapper (at least temporarily while you're still debugging) and just let the exception happen, so you can see the actual full error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you. this helped me fix my export error which led me to fixing my import error and now everything works perfectly!